# exe build with cygwin gcc hanging when running in cygwin terminal

Tags: cygwin

I build an exe named DatalogTest.exe with cygwin gcc.

When I try to run this (./DatalogText.exe), I just hangs. I can not kill it with Ctrl-C, suspend it with Ctrl-Z or kill it by doing a kill -9 in another shell.

strace gives this output, and then it hangs:

```
$ strace DatalogTest.exe
    1       1 [main] DatalogTest (94016) **********************************************
   71      72 [main] DatalogTest (94016) Program name: C:\Project\hpj_main_LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test\DatalogTest.exe (windows pid 94016)
   51     123 [main] DatalogTest (94016) OS version:   Windows NT-6.1
   24     147 [main] DatalogTest (94016) **********************************************
  427     574 [main] DatalogTest (94016) sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x6123E468, 0x610FCAB0)
  309     883 [main] DatalogTest 94016 open_shared: name shared.5, n 5, shared 0x60FF0000 (wanted 0x60FF0000), h 0x8C, *m 6
   66     949 [main] DatalogTest 94016 heap_init: heap base 0x80000000, heap top 0x80000000, heap size 0x18000000 (402653184)
   38     987 [main] DatalogTest 94016 open_shared: name S-1-5-21-1408293143-2956554002-1949004742-1377.1, n 1, shared 0x60FE0000 (wanted 0x60FE0000), h 0x88, *m 6
   35    1022 [main] DatalogTest 94016 user_info::create: opening user shared for 'S-1-5-21-1408293143-2956554002-1949004742-1377' at 0x60FE0000
   35    1057 [main] DatalogTest 94016 user_info::create: user shared version 6467403B
   54    1111 [main] DatalogTest 94016 fhandler_pipe::create: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-94016-sigwait, size 164, mode PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
   49    1160 [main] DatalogTest 94016 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe read handle 0xA0
   18    1178 [main] DatalogTest 94016 fhandler_pipe::create: CreateFile: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-94016-sigwait
   33    1211 [main] DatalogTest 94016 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe write handle 0xA4
   43    1254 [main] DatalogTest 94016 dll_crt0_0: finished dll_crt0_0 initialization
  387    1641 [main] DatalogTest 94016 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\Project\hpj_main_LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test, no-keep-rel, no-add-slash)
   31    1672 [main] DatalogTest 94016 normalize_win32_path: C:\Project\hpj_main_LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test = normalize_win32_path (C:\Project\hpj_main_LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test)
   20    1692 [main] DatalogTest 94016 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Project/hpj_main_LFC/ControlMicro/ServiceLayer/Datalog/Test = conv_to_posix_path (C:\Project\hpj_main_LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test)
  118    1810 [sig] DatalogTest 94016 wait_sig: entering ReadFile loop, my_readsig 0xA0, my_sendsig 0xA4
```

The build works on another machinne.

Here the strace output:

```
 3531    3531 [main] DatalogTest (2868) **********************************************
  100    3631 [main] DatalogTest (2868) Program name: C:\Jenkins-workspace\Lodam\Embedded\LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test\DatalogTest.exe (windows pid 2868)
   46    3677 [main] DatalogTest (2868) OS version:   Windows NT-6.1
   38    3715 [main] DatalogTest (2868) **********************************************
  383    4098 [main] DatalogTest (2868) sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x6123D468, 0x610FBA10)
  303    4401 [main] DatalogTest 2868 open_shared: name shared.5, n 5, shared 0x60FF0000 (wanted 0x60FF0000), h 0x80, *m 6
   64    4465 [main] DatalogTest 2868 heap_init: heap base 0x80000000, heap top 0x80000000, heap size 0x18000000 (402653184)
   66    4531 [main] DatalogTest 2868 open_shared: name S-1-5-21-1408293143-2956554002-1949004742-2274.1, n 1, shared 0x60FE0000 (wanted 0x60FE0000), h 0x78, *m 6
   46    4577 [main] DatalogTest 2868 user_info::create: opening user shared for 'S-1-5-21-1408293143-2956554002-1949004742-2274' at 0x60FE0000
   44    4621 [main] DatalogTest 2868 user_info::create: user shared version 6467403B
   71    4692 [main] DatalogTest 2868 fhandler_pipe::create: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-2868-sigwait, size 164, mode PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE
  283    4975 [main] DatalogTest 2868 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe read handle 0x94
   67    5042 [main] DatalogTest 2868 fhandler_pipe::create: CreateFile: name \\.\pipe\cygwin-c5e39b7a9d22bafb-2868-sigwait
  184    5226 [main] DatalogTest 2868 fhandler_pipe::create: pipe write handle 0x98
   62    5288 [main] DatalogTest 2868 dll_crt0_0: finished dll_crt0_0 initialization
  654    5942 [sig] DatalogTest 2868 wait_sig: entering ReadFile loop, my_readsig 0x94, my_sendsig 0x98
  180    6122 [main] DatalogTest 2868 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: conv_to_posix_path (C:\Jenkins-workspace\Lodam\Embedded\LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test, no-keep-rel, no-add-slash)
   83    6205 [main] DatalogTest 2868 normalize_win32_path: C:\Jenkins-workspace\Lodam\Embedded\LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test = normalize_win32_path (C:\Jenkins-workspace\Lodam\Embedded\LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test)
   52    6257 [main] DatalogTest 2868 mount_info::conv_to_posix_path: /cygdrive/c/Jenkins-workspace/Lodam/Embedded/LFC/ControlMicro/ServiceLayer/Datalog/Test = conv_to_posix_path (C:\Jenkins-workspace\Lodam\Embedded\LFC\ControlMicro\ServiceLayer\Datalog\Test)
   83    6340 [main] DatalogTest 2868 sigprocmask: 0 = sigprocmask (0, 0x800180A8, 0x610FBA10)
  202    6542 [main] DatalogTest 2868 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 0: not open
   46    6588 [main] DatalogTest 2868 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 1: not open
   40    6628 [main] DatalogTest 2868 _cygwin_istext_for_stdio: fd 2: not open
  136    6764 [main] DatalogTest (2868) open_shared: name cygpid.2868, n 2868, shared 0x60FD0000 (wanted 0x60FD0000), h 0xC0, *m 2
   57    6821 [main] DatalogTest 2868 pinfo::thisproc: myself dwProcessId 2868
   42    6863 [main] DatalogTest 2868 time: 1370262553 = time(0)
 2768    9631 [main] DatalogTest 2868 environ_init: GetEnvironmentStrings returned 0xCE4D48
   87    9718 [main] DatalogTest 2868 environ_init: 0x80028290: !::=::\
   77    9795 [main] DatalogTest 2868 environ_init: 0x800282A0: ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
```

etc.

On both machines:

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.3

On machine with hang:

uname -r
1.7.18(0.263/5/3)

Windows version:
Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1

On other machine:

$ uname -r
1.7.18(0.263/5/3)

Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, Service Pack 1

Comment: Have you checked the Win7 machine for [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda)?

Comment: Yes, but have not found any this far. Disabled Symantec Endpoint Protection. No change.

Comment: As noted there, disabling BLODA isn't always enough, sometimes it has to be uninstalled.  But it would be helpful if you could show the code you're using if you want someone to be able to try to reproduce it.

Comment: Hmmm. I am confused. Now my programs run.The only thing, that I can imagine has done a change, is that I yesterday updated cygwin to version 1.7.19(0.266/5/3).